pythonの出力をsortする方法
pythonを使いmake10を自動でやってくれるコードをつくっていたのですが、出力をした際abcdについてうまく順番に出力されるのを期待していたところ、ぐちゃぐちゃになって出てきてしまいました。コードは以下の通りです。
import itertools

# 符号の組み合わせ
opers = set([y for z in itertools.combinations_with_replacement("+-*/", 3)
            for y in itertools.permutations(z, 3)])
# 計算式パターンのモデル
models = ["({a}{x}{b}){y}({c}{z}{d})",
        "(({a}{x}{b}){y}{c}){z}{d}",
        "{a}{x}({b}{y}({c}{z}{d}))",
        "({a}{x}({b}{y}{c})){z}{d}",
        "{a}{x}(({b}{y}{c}){z}{d})"]

kotae = []
n = 10
i = 0
kaisu = 0
for a in range(10):
    for b in range(10):
        for c in range(10):
            for d in range(10):
                kaisu = 0
                for oper in opers:
                    for model in models:
                        try:
                            tmp = model.format(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d,
                                            x=oper[0], y=oper[1], z=oper[2])
                            if eval(tmp) == n:
                                i += 1
                                kaisu += 1
                                tmp += "," + str(kaisu)
                                kotae.append(tmp)
                        except ZeroDivisionError:
                            continue

print(set(kotae))
print(i)


a, b, c, d の値の順序を保持する場合、ordered-set · PyPI を利用する方法があります。
--- make10.py   2024-06-08 19:01:15.045427145 +0900
+++ make10_OrderedSet.py        2024-06-08 19:02:47.648736157 +0900
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 import itertools
+from ordered_set import OrderedSet
 
 # 符号の組み合わせ
 opers = set([y for z in itertools.combinations_with_replacement("+-*/", 3)
@@ -10,7 +11,7 @@
         "({a}{x}({b}{y}{c})){z}{d}",
         "{a}{x}(({b}{y}{c}){z}{d})"]
 
-kotae = []
+kotae = OrderedSet()
 n = 10
 i = 0
 kaisu = 0
@@ -28,9 +29,9 @@
                                 i += 1
                                 kaisu += 1
                                 tmp += "," + str(kaisu)
-                                kotae.append(tmp)
+                                kotae.add(tmp)
                         except ZeroDivisionError:
                             continue
 
-print(set(kotae))
+print(kotae)
 print(i)


kotae をなぜ set に変換するのか良くわかりませんが
下記のようにして set をソートすることもできます。
参考URL
set（集合）型 --- set, frozenset
※ ここには「コレクションには順序がないので、集合は挿入の順序や要素の位置を記録しません。」とあります。
　Sorting Techniques
■ set から list に変換して sorted でソートします。
質問のプログラムを下記のように変更します。
先頭に下記の　import を追加します。
import operator

kotae にソートキーを含めたタプルとして追加します。
kotae.append((a, b , c , d, tmp))

kotae を set に変換します。
set1 = set(kotae)

set を list に変換してソートします。
list1 = sorted(list(set1), key=operator.itemgetter(0,1,2,3))
for tuple1 in list1:
    print(f"{tuple1[4]}")

実際は演算子があるのでkotaeの順序とは一致しないかもしれません。
